# Como Cambiar el titulo de una ventana de consola de Python

Tags: python, consola

tengo una "Aplicación" de Python que es basada en consola y quisiera saber si se puede cambiar el Nombre de la Consola [image: Me refiero a esto]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba esto:

```
import os
os.system("title mi titulo")
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En linux puedes cambiar el título asi ([referencia](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=85567)):

```
import sys
sys.stdout.write("\x1b]2;mi titulo\x07")
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: `os.system` ejecuta un comando; no cambia el título de la ventana.

Comment: Exacto, a lo mejor con algún compilador como PY2EXE?

Comment: pequeño gazapo, arreglado. Por favor @CandidMoe quita voto negativo se crees que ahora la respuesta es correcta.

Comment: Momento eso es en la shell o en un script que tu escribiste

Comment: Suponiendo que dispones del código python de la aplicacion, tienes que añadir esas dos líneas de código en tu aplicación.

Comment: No funciona en Linux.

Comment: @CandidMoe En Linux no funciona debido a que el hace os.system() y del sistema en este caso Windows cambia el atributo de titulo como indica en el string con la palabra title, a lo mejor en Linux el nombre del atributo es distinto, en windows si funciona pero si o si el atributo title debe estar en el string

Comment: Si sabes como puedo cambiar el icono puede ser de mucha ayuda

Comment: Hola, @CandidMoe me has obligado a googlear y arrancar mi linux para probar el código... jejeje... añadido a la respuesta

Comment: Tendre que hacer 2 compilaciones una para Linux y otra pa' windows y el que tiene mac que se joda

Comment: jaja... por si te sirve para ahorrarte las dos compilaciones, puedes averiguar el SO consultando [sys.platform](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.platform)